# Information about VSphere sdk Java Service export several objects.

Tags: java, vsphere, vmware-sdk

At the moment I am trying to create a vsphere web service. I have exported all the necessary back - end class as well as some other parsers. The idea is that I need to extend DataProviderAdapter probably to send and receive information from the GUI. Here comes the problem, I am not that experienced with the technology. Unfortunately, the documentation of the vmware sdk was not that clear and I am still lost. The idea is how to send and receive different data according to the GUI. For example, the GUI wants to show information about the host and send it that request to me, what I need to do and how. Here is the example of what I have done so far:

public abstract class DataObject implements DataProviderAdapter 
{

```
class ResourceType implements ResourceTypeResolver
{

    /**
     * A method parses a given URI and return a String containing the type of 
     * custom object to which the URI pertains. For example, 
     * for a URI that referred to a given custom DataObject object, 
     * the getResourceType() method must return the String “samples:DataObject”.
     */

    @Override
    public String getResourceType(URI uri)
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * The getServerGuid() method parsed a given URI and returns a String containing 
     * the server global unique identifier for the URI target object, if any.
     */
    @Override
    public String getServerGuid(URI uri)
    {
        return null;
    }
        public DataObject(DataService dataService, ResourceTypeResolverRegistry typeResolverRegistry)
{
    if (null == dataService || null == typeResolverRegistry)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("Some of the arguments is null!");
    }

    this.dataService = dataService;
    try
    {


    }catch(UnsupportedOperationException unsupportedOperation)
    {
        logger.warning("ModelObjectUriResolver registration failed:" +  unsupportedOperation.getMessage());
    }
}
```

If someone of you have some experience and can share the examples I will be really thankful. Cheers!